# Java try-catch statement inside while loop

Tags: java, try-catch

I have this method and it works fine. I need to put a try/catch statement so
the method can continue if the user puts in a letter. I don't know where to put the statement, It seems everywhere I put it it get's wrong. Could somebody please show me where to put this statement?

```
public void myMethod() {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int array[] = new int[21];
    int number;

    boolean end = false;

    while (!end) {

        System.out.println("Please give an number between 0-20: ");
        number = in.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {

            if (i == number) {

                System.out.println(array[number]);
                end = true;
            }
        }
        if (!end) {
            System.out.println("I cant find number " + number
                    + " in the array, please try again ");
        }

    }

 }
```

Comment: What do you mean "it gets wrong"? And just adding `try { some parts of your code }` will not help; as you have to think on what should happen when the input provided by the user is not a number.

Comment: It loops and prints until stackoverflow

Comment: How can I solve this if the user input is not a number?

Comment: public void myMethod() throw Exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loop I can't explain, you need only check values between 0 and 20,
And when you call try catch, you have to skip loop after exception

```
public static void myMethod() {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int array[] = new int[21];
    int number=0;

    boolean end = false;

    while (!end) {


        System.out.println("Please give an number between 0-20: ");
        //check symbol
        try{
            number = Integer.valueOf(in.next());
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("It's not a number! ");
            continue; //skip loop
        }

        if((number>=0)&&(number<=20))
        {
              System.out.println(array[number]);
              end=true;
        }
        else
             System.out.println("I cant find number " + number
                        + " in the array, please try again ");

        /* why do you use loop here???
         * u need to check if number between 0-20
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {

            if (i == number) {

                System.out.println(array[number]);
                end = true;
            }
        }*/


    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.out.println("Please give an number between 0-20: ");
    try{
        number = in.nextInt();
    }catch(Exception e){
        number = 1; //Put random number of default number here
    }
```

Comment: I tried that with a number outside the array but it loops and prints all the time. If I put a random number of default like 1 it prints that element of the array and that's not what this method is supposed to do

Comment: What is the method suppose to do?

Comment: It's just an excersise and I need to ouput the the element from the array that's given from the user. It works good, but if the user hits an letter it crashes

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Test test = new Test();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int array[] = new int[21];  
    int number;
    System.out.println("Please give an number between 0-20: ");
    do{
        try{
            number = Integer.parseInt(in.next());
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Please give an number between 0-20: ");
            number = -1;
        }
    }
    while(!(number <= 20 && number >=0 ));
    System.out.println(array[number]);
}
```